# Problems with sqlite3 android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

While working on my database lectures, I had to work in Terminal. I had to attach to device, see if my folder was created and had to run some sqlite3 commands. While accessing my files from adb, I was using these commands:

```
C:\Users\PC\AndroidStudioProjects\ToDo>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device


C:\Users\PC\AndroidStudioProjects\ToDo>adb root

C:\Users\PC\AndroidStudioProjects\ToDo>adb shell
generic_x86:/ $ cd data
generic_x86:/data $ cd data
generic_x86:/data/data $ cd com.example.todo
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/data/com.example.todo: Permission denied
2|generic_x86:/data/data $
```

Then I found out that for some reason my root won't work so I had to get access to folder with my package name with code 
`run-as package name` . When I got access to my folder I was instructed to run sqlite3 command by just typing `sqlite3 DATABASE_NAME` and got this

```
127|generic_x86:/data/data/com.example.todo/databases $ sqlite3 ToDoDatabase
sh: sqlite3: inaccessible or not found
```

I checked if I had sqlite3 in platform tools and it was there. I have path added to `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` , and I know adb is working so I'm out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Comment: Using a dir command you can see the database file, it's definitely there and created?

Comment: i've never used dir command, but i used device file explored and found database and database-journal if that is what ur asking